# useState() not updating inside of useEffect() hook

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, state

I'm having a problem updating useState() inside of useEffect(). I think I may be running into an infinite loop and useState isn't updating regardless of the booleans that I pass in. It always shows false.

```
export const useAlert = () => {
  const action = useSelector(state => state.edit.action);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const booleanA = true;

  const booleanB = false;

  const [isOverMax, setIsOverMax] = useState(false);
  const reset = () => {
    dispatch(resetEditAction());
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsOverMax(booleanA || booleanB);
  }, isOverMax);

  return [isOverMax, reset];
};
```

For more context, `booleanA` and `booleanB` are dynamically generated with other code, but even when they are hardcoded like above, `isOverMax` only ever is `false`. I can never get a true value, even when both booleans are hardcoded as true.

Comment: First make sure to write `useEffect(() => {
    setIsOverMax(booleanA || booleanB);
  }, [isOverMax]);`

Second, I would be careful updating state inside a useEffect some unexpected side effects may occur

Comment: Disclaimer: I'ma JS noob so... Have you tried writing `console.log(isOverMax)` inside the useEffect? Because JS is single threaded, there's a possibility you just immediately viewed the return value of this function. Wherever this is being called,  you can also run an interval that logs the value to console. It could be set to true, but you never noticed due to the queue of ops. BTW +1 Drew Reese's comment. Your IDE may point this out for you; if not, then you can run eslint with a React/Vue plugin/preset and it'll tell you what you should have.

Comment: Your `useEffect` dependency is incorrect, it should be an array. Also, you don't want any dependencies in that array that the `useEffect` callback updates, i.e. if calling `setIsOverMax` then `isOverMax` shouldn't be a dependency without a conditional check on the state updater. My guess is that your dependency should be `[booleanA, booleanB]` since these are what are referenced in the effect callback. Can you update your question to include a more accurate code representation?

Comment: @HansKrohn After some more learning, I'm thinking an empty dependency array is more preferable to updating state inside the use effect hook. This might cause infinite loop and rendering issues. And a populated dependency array with the correct values would be an even better option.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks for pointing out the incorrect dependency array.

Comment: @ElinaMcGill Yea, I was just drawing up why it wasn’t working, and that was the fact the dependency array was missing. However, it’s important to note since you are changing Boolean, this will never run an infinite loop it will just run twice. Reason for this, if the state is updated to `false` it would trigger the useEffect again only to set the state to `false` again. Since the state is the same again it would not trigger a new re-render, and the useEffect will not be triggered again. So this will just at most run twice, but again this may cause unexpected side effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The state `isOverMax` is derived from `booleanA` and `booleanB`. Thus `isOverMax` should change whenever `booleanA` or `booleanB` is changed. You should reflect this in your dependency array.

```
 useEffect(() => {
   setIsOverMax(booleanA || booleanB);
 }, [booleanA, booleanB]);
```

Here is the working example. Just click "Show code snippet" and then "Run code Snippet"

```js
const useAlert = () => {
  const [booleanA, setA] = React.useState(true);
  const [booleanB, setB] = React.useState(false);
  const [isOverMax, setIsOverMax] =React. useState(false);

  const reset = () => {
    setA(false);
    setB(false);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setIsOverMax(booleanA || booleanB);
  }, [booleanA , booleanB]);

  // just for testing
  const toggleA = () => {
    setA((a) => !a);
  }

   return [isOverMax, reset, toggleA];
};

const App = () => {
  const [alert, reset, toggleA]  = useAlert();
  return <div>
    isOverMax={"" + alert}<br/>
    <button onClick={() => toggleA()} >Toggle A</button>
    <button onClick={() => reset()} >Reset </button>
  </div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Since the states `booleanA` and `booleanB` already exist, they will trigger a rerender when one of them is changed. Thus you can just return the calculation of `isOverMax`

```
const useAlert = () => {

   // ...
   return [booleanA || booleanB, reset];
}
```

```js
    const useAlert = () => {
      const [booleanA, setA] = React.useState(true);
      const [booleanB, setB] = React.useState(false);
      const isOverMax = booleanA || booleanB;

      const reset = () => {
        setA(false);
        setB(false);
      };

      // just for testing
      const toggleA = () => {
        setA((a) => !a);
      }

       return [isOverMax, reset, toggleA];
    };

    const App = () => {
      const [alert, reset, toggleA]  = useAlert();
      return <div>
        isOverMax={"" + alert}<br/>
        <button onClick={() => toggleA()} >Toggle A</button>
        <button onClick={() => reset()} >Reset </button>
      </div>;
    };

    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**EDIT**

> Are there any general guidelines for when NOT to use the effect hook so I don't start throwing it in code where it isn't crucial?

Not really, but you should have read [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). The rules tell you what you should do to prevent unpredictable behavior. Sadly they don't explain the reasons for that rule and this question is the wrong place to explain it all. Thus please open another question if you still have one.

Comment: This was such a thorough answer with two different solutions that solved my problem. It helped clarify the dependency array and how that functions in general. I also liked the second solution that avoided the use of `useEffect` in general. Are there any general guidelines for when NOT to use the effect hook so I don't start throwing it in code where it isn't crucial?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `isOverMax` in dependencies of `useEffect` to avoid infinite loop

```
useEffect(() => {
  setIsOverMax(booleanA || booleanB);
}, []);
```